# Spring Security connecting authentification with a database

Tags: spring, maven, tomcat

I'm new to spring security with tomcat, i've beeing following a video, and i did everything there but when i try to login i get a HTTP 500 Error: 
with the exception: `javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception`
and root cause : `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils`

Here is my spring-config file:

```
<authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/formation" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="dataSource"  ref="dataSource"/> 
    </beans:bean>
```

and the pom:

```
.
.
.
 <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
.
.
.
```

the error says NoClassDefFoundError but i don't know about what class is he talking about?
what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You most likely have a version mismatch between some of your Maven dependencies or you are missing a dependency.  Can you post your entire pom.xml?

Comment: were you able to fix this issue ?